# Mongo DB Delete a field and value

Tags: mongodb

In mongo shell how would I delete all occurrences of  `"id" : "1"` the value of the field is always different. Would I use the $unset operator? Would that delete the value and the field?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're saying remove all occurrences of the field, right?  If so, then it should be like this:

```
db.collection.update( 
    { id: { $exists: true } },  // criteria
    { $unset: { id: 1 } },      // modifier
    false,                      // no need to upsert
    true                        // multi-update
);
```

Comment: wont this just delete the field id:1? I want to delete all assurances of the field `id`

Comment: @Jacinto No, the code block in my answer will remove all instances of *id*.  The *id: 1* syntax is misleading, but the *1* really means "true".  See here:  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24unset